# Getting the error: "nmake" not found in path when trying to create / migrate / run

Tags: visual-studio, erlang, elixir, nmake

Currently on Window's 10 with Visual Studio Build Tools installed, elixir 1.10.4, erlang/otp 22.  I'm trying to run an api locally that is built on phoenix/elixir, and am running into an error where argon2_elixir cannot compile, and the error causing it is "nmake" not found in path.  I have been trying to research the issue and most solutions say to make sure Visual C++ build tools are installed, and that didn't seem to help the situation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

With newer Visual Studio versions, nmake.exe is located in a path which depends on the exact version of the C++ runtime/build tools. To locate it in a mostly version independent fashion, I use a batch script containing the following code snippet:

```
set VSPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional
for /f %%i in ('dir "%VSPATH%\VC\Tools\MSVC" /b') do set VCTOOLSVERSION=%%i
set NMAKE="%VSPATH%\VC\Tools\MSVC\%VCTOOLSVERSION%\bin\HostX86\x86\nmake.exe"
```

(for the 64 bit version replace HostX86\x86 by Hostx64\x64).

You can surely adapt this to your needs, for example, for finding the folder to `nmake.exe` and adding it to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I found the exact path and added it to the PATH environment variable in windows, and still ran into the same error.  I tried updated the path for both the user and the system, still no luck.

Comment: @JoshDowns: sorry, but *"cannot compile, and the error causing it is "nmake" not found in path"* is not really an error description suitable for anything more than telling you to update the PATH variable. I guess for this case you need to debug the build process in detail.

Comment: This question is old but I found an easy solution to use `nmake`. I realized that `nmake` is no longer set in the `PATH` variable. I used the `Visual Studio 20XX command prompt` and then Voila! nmake was there. I think the command prompt has it in its path but not the system variables.